# Dont recognize end of line in python?

Tags: python, networkx, eof

I'm working on graphs in networkx, this is the code:

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import OrderedDict
import codecs

g = nx.DiGraph()

sadrzaj= list()

dat = codecs.open("petra.txt", "r")

for rijec in dat.read().split():
    sadrzaj.append(rijec)


for i, rijec in enumerate(sadrzaj):
    try:
        sljedeca_rijec = sadrzaj[i+1]
        if not g.has_node(rijec):
            g.add_node(rijec)
            g.node[rijec]['pojavljivanje'] = 1
        else:
            g.node[rijec]['pojavljivanje'] += 1
        if not g.has_node(sljedeca_rijec):
            g.add_node(sljedeca_rijec)
            g.node[sljedeca_rijec]['pojavljivanje'] = 0        
        if rijec.endswith('\n') == False:
           if not g.has_edge(rijec,sljedeca_rijec):
                    g.add_edge(rijec,sljedeca_rijec,weight = 1)    
           else:
               g.edge[rijec][sljedeca_rijec]['weight'] +=1

    except IndexError:
            if not g.has_node(rijec):
                g.add_node(rijec)
                g.node[rijec]['pojavljivanje'] = 1
            else:        
                g.node[rijec]['pojavljivanje'] += 1
    except:
        raise


for u,v in g.nodes(data = True):
    print " Cvor " , u , " pojavljuje se: " , v , " puta."

for u,v,d in g.edges(data = True):
   print "Veza *",u," - ",v,"* ima tezinu: ",d

dat.close()
```

But in part:
    if rijec.endswith('\n') == False:
python doesnt recognize that \n in txt document so I get the edge between last word in the sentence and first in the other sentence.

In txt document are sentences without any . , ? !, only letters, and each new sentence is in the new line.

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: This consumed all whitespace, including newlines: `dat.read().split()`.  If you want to iterate line by line you should forget about reading the file into a list and just do `for i, rijec in enumerate(dat):` and then split the line further on whitespace inside that loop.

Comment: Files iterate over lines and keep their newline ending.  So if I do `for line in dat:` then `line` will include a line of text terminated by a newline character.  If there are no newline characters it will contain the whole file.  The problem with your code is that you used `split()` with no arguments which splits on all whitespace *including newlines*.

Comment: each word is node and edge between exist if words are one after another. in my example edge exist even between last word in first sentence and first word in second sentence, regardless new line. and that is the only problem

Comment: I'm a little unclear how you expect the code to know that a sentence has ended.  Reading your question, I think you're saying that each sentence is its own line.  Is that correct?  If so, then the problem is that `.read().split()` has removed all white space, including newlines [as @StevenRumbalski says].  Instead you should iterate over each line separately.